# Woocommerce - Default quantity for grouped product

Tags: woocommerce

When using grouped products in Woocommerce the defaulted quantity of every product within a group is 0. How can I change this default quantity to 1?

I want someone to add all childproducts from within a group to the cart with one click. Default all quantities are set to 0, so they'd have to set all seperate quantities to 1 before clicking the add to cart button. If I could preset all the quantities to 1, they'd only have to click add to cart.

Comment: I'd also like to have a different default of like 10. Anyone know the answer?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no filter in the file given in the other answer to use, I don't recommend editing the core file.

You can use the following filter, but I can't seem to identify the product type as 'grouped', So these settings will be applied for every product input (which I want to be 1 for evertyhing, so no problem).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity', 10, 2 );
function custom_quantity( $args, $product ) {
    $args['input_value'] = 1;
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: For those reading. This solution sets all the qty inputs in the shopping cart to 1, no matter how many of a single product are in the cart.

Comment: For those like me that are new with wordpress and wooCommerce, this code have to be added in the `functions.php` from your [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#using-functions-php).

Answer (score 0):

I have modified Sormano's solution to fix the issue raised by Joao.

Here's the updated code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity', 10, 2 );
function custom_quantity( $args, $product ) {
    $args['input_value'] = empty($args['input_value']) ? 1 : $args['input_value'];
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity', 10, 2 );
function custom_quantity( $args, $product ) {
    if (is_page(8)) {
    return $args;
    } else {
    $args['input_value'] = 1;
    return $args;
    }
}
```

Change 8 to your cart page id.

Answer (score -1):

You could modify line 49 in grouped.php

> path: wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/grouped.php

Change the 0 at the end of:

```
<?php woocommerce_quantity_input( array( 'input_name' => 'quantity['.$child_product['product']->id.']', 'input_value' => '0' ) ); ?>
```

To 1 (or 10 or whatever default quantity you want):

```
<?php woocommerce_quantity_input( array( 'input_name' => 'quantity['.$child_product['product']->id.']', 'input_value' => '1' ) ); ?>
```

It's a bit hacky (since there's no discrimination between different types of grouped products), but in my case, I only had 1 TYPE of grouped product to begin with, so this fix was doable for what I needed.

I'm sure you could mess with the php further to customize this to each type, but that might become painful.

Another *potential* option is this woocommerce plugin: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/minmax-quantities/

But I haven't tried it, so I can't speak to its effectiveness.