# Show only one child product (of grouped product) to have a quantity of 1 in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

By default, all child products under a grouped product show a quantity of "0" on the single listing page [as shown here](https://images.app.goo.gl/evAFm1whigAonxd16).

There's a way to [change ALL the quantities from "0" to "1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262048/woocommerce-default-quantity-for-grouped-product) but can we only choose the first child product to have a quantity of 1?

Comment: Grouped product has nothing to do with the quantity. Its just holding ids of products that could be simple or variable products. In each simple or variable product you can set minimum quantity.

Comment: Best way to get it done is to copy grouped.php template in your theme and just check if this is the first product from the array of products and set your values. Another option is java/jq to modify input.